# Javascript - Validate if image is same origin before doing a canvas.toDataURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, canvas

I have a cropping utility, built with AngularJs, part of the utility is that it can crop any image in the browser using the canvas.toDataURL method, the problem is that it's not possible to call this method on and image that is not from the same origin, doing so will cause a SecurityError breaking up the rest of the code. So my question is:

**Is there a way to validate if an image complies with the same origin policy before trying the toDataURL method?**

I've been searching about this but all answers I find relate to making changes to the request in the server so that all images show up as same origin, but I want to distribute this code so I have no way of making sure the user will always use a same origin image, so I want to automatically disable the canvas cropping for images that don't comply with this.

Comment: [try {} catch (ex) {}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) or img `onerror` handler

Comment: check the "src" attribute of the image and see if it's from the same domain

Comment: Thank you @LJ_1102 I was able to catch the error and show a warning to console, didn't thought about using a try-catch block. Cheers!